# packing using tkinter in_ keyword doesn't work with widgets created outside of a frame subclass

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My understanding is that the `in_` keyword argument to pack/grid should allow me to specify the managing widget. I want to pack arbitrary widgets inside a Frame subclass, so I passed the widgets and packed them during intialization, but the widgets didn't appear (although space in the window appears to have been allocated...). If I create the widget internally using `master` which is `root`, there is no issue and the widgets are displayed as expected.

The following working example and its output demonstrate the issue:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ItemContainerExternal(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, input_label, input_object):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.label = input_label
        self.label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=3, fill=tk.X, in_=self)
        self.input_object = input_object
        self.input_object.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=3, fill=tk.X, in_=self)

    def get(self):
        return variable.get()

class ItemContainerInternal(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        ttk.Label(master, text='internal').pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=3, fill=tk.X, in_=self)
        self.input_object = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.input_object.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=3, fill=tk.X, in_=self)

    def get(self):
        return variable.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    inputobj = ttk.Entry(root)
    inputlabel = ttk.Label(root, text='external')
    ItemContainerExternal(root, inputlabel, inputobj).grid(row=0, column=0)
    ItemContainerInternal(root).grid(row=1, column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating the entry and label before you're creating the frame, so they have a lower stacking order. That means the frame will be on top of the entry and label and thus, obscuring them from view.

A simple fix is to call `lift()` on the entry and label:

```
class ItemContainerExternal(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, input_label, input_object):
        ...
        self.input_object.lift()
        self.label.lift()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: or `.lower()` on the frame.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which widgets get created matters. Newer widgets are "on top of" previous widgets.

Call `.lower()` on the Frame after you create it, assuming it's created after all the widgets that you will pack into it.  If not, you'll need to either call `.lower()` again on the Frame after creating a new widget to go inside it, or you'll have to raise the new widget via `.lift()` as per Bryan's answer.